# Universal linking not working on iOS in Flutter due to XCode

Tags: flutter, ios-universal-links

## What I have:

I have a flutter app and I am using the unilink plugin to forward deeplinks.
On Android, everthing works as intended, but not on iOS.

This is my iOS json:

http://connector.horizonpedia.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

and these are my XCode .entitlement Settings:

[image]

I also checked my URL params in Info.plist:

[image]

Json passed the test on https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

I am pretty sure I have done everything correctly except ticking this box

## Problem:

as you can see, the target runner checkbox is unticked and I can't tick it by clicking on it.

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, 2 things:

- make sure your AASA file is served from:
  https://catalogscanner.horizonpedia.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
  (notice the `https` and the `catalogscanner` part)
- in your AASA file, you are currently using: `"paths": [ "\*" ]`, it should be `"paths": [ "/*" ]`

Give it a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

as you describe, URL identifier should be the actual url/uri, URL schemes is your header like http, https or custome scheme like [some_name]. After edit this you should stop and run from the beginning, not hot restart to apply. I paste the link in safari and it's work like a charm.

[image]